# Pandas : How to create an algorithm that helps me improve results and creating new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, pandas-groupby

it's a little bit complicated , i have this dataframe :

```
ID           TimeandDate        Date       Time
10   2020-08-07 07:40:09  2022-08-07   07:40:09
10   2020-08-07 08:50:00  2022-08-07   08:50:00
10   2020-08-07 12:40:09  2022-08-07   12:40:09
10   2020-08-08 07:40:09  2022-08-08   07:40:09
10   2020-08-08 17:40:09  2022-08-08   17:40:09
12   2020-08-07 08:03:09  2022-08-07   08:03:09
12   2020-08-07 10:40:09  2022-08-07   10:40:09
12   2020-08-07 14:40:09  2022-08-07   14:40:09
12   2020-08-07 16:40:09  2022-08-07   16:40:09
13   2020-08-07 09:22:45  2022-08-07   09:22:45
13   2020-08-07 17:57:06  2022-08-07   17:57:06
```

i want to create new dataframe with 2 new columns the first one is `df["Check-in"]` , as you can see my data doesnt have any indicator to show what time the id has checked in , so i will suppose that the first time for every id is a check-in , and the next row is a check-out and will be inserted in `df["Check-out"]` , also if a `check-in` doesnt have a `check-out` time it has to be registred as the `check-out` for the previous `check-out` of the same day

i tried this but i'm afraid its not efficient because it shows the first and last one imagine if `ID=13` has entered at `07:40:09` and the he check out at `08:40:09` , later that day he returns at `19:20:00` and leave in the next 10 minutes `19:30:00` if i do that fonction it will show that he worked for 12 hours

```
group = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])
def TimeDifference(df):
    in = df['TimeandDate'].min()
    out = df['TimeandDate'].max()
    df2 = p.DataFrame([in-out], columns=['TimeDiff'])
    return df2
group.apply(TimeDifference)
```

**Result Desired**

```
ID         Date   Check-in    Check-out
10   2020-08-07   07:40:09     12:40:09
10   2020-08-08   07:40:09     17:40:09
12   2020-08-07   08:03:09     10:40:09
12   2020-08-07   14:40:09     16:40:09 
13   2020-08-07   09:22:45     17:57:06
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Is efficiency your main concern? Because I believe your code is not working.

Comment: Yes actually , imagine if `ID=13` has entered at `07:40:09` and the he check out at `08:40:09` , later that day he returns at `19:20:00` and leave in the next 10 minutes `19:30:00` if i do that fonction it will show that he worked for 12 hours

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this. The man/woman with `ID=13` did not come back on the same day. He/She came back the day after. Anyway, I will try to answer your question based on what I have grasped.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
df["TimeandDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TimeandDate"])
df.set_index("TimeandDate", inplace=True)
print(df.groupby([df["ID"], df.index.year, df.index.month, df.index.day]).agg(["min", "max"]).to_markdown())
```

##### Output

| (ID, Y, m, d) | ('Date', 'min') | ('Date', 'max') | ('Time', 'min') | ('Time', 'max') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (10, 2020, 8, 7) | 2022-08-07 | 2022-08-07 | 07:40:09 | 12:40:09 |
| (10, 2020, 8, 8) | 2022-08-08 | 2022-08-08 | 07:40:09 | 17:40:09 |
| (12, 2020, 8, 7) | 2022-08-07 | 2022-08-07 | 08:03:09 | 16:40:09 |
| (13, 2020, 8, 7) | 2022-08-07 | 2022-08-07 | 09:22:45 | 17:57:06 |

Comment: Thanks Amir i'll try it out

Comment: @Smordy I hope it comes in handy, Smordy. If you get any errors, do not hesitate to comment here.  I might be able to improve the answer based on your comment.

Comment: i really appreciate it Amir, your way is working , but the  output that i want  show is exactly what @Yolao_21 does , in somedays `ID` have multiple check-in and check out daily and sometimes its missing a check-out so the last checkout must be replaced with the row before him

Answer (score 1):

This approach is going to be verbose and not speedy but might solve the problem for now.

I first assign a suffix-pair to each ID/Date pair, then check if there is a check-in without check-out (so if the length is not even, it means there is a missing check-out).

The output is the same as your desired output

```
new_col = []
for i in df.ID.unique():
    for d in df.Date.unique():
        p = df.loc[(df.ID==i)&(df.Date==d)]
        suffix = sorted(list(range(1,len(p)))*2)[:len(p)]
        if len(suffix)%2!=0 and len(suffix)>1:
            suffix[-2]=np.nan
            suffix[-1]-=1
        new_col.extend(suffix)

df['new'] = new_col
df.dropna().groupby(['ID','Date','new'], as_index=False).agg({'Time':[min,max]}).drop('new', axis=1, level=0)

Output:
ID  Date    Time
                    min         max
0   10  2022-08-07  07:40:09    12:40:09
1   10  2022-08-08  07:40:09    17:40:09
2   12  2022-08-07  08:03:09    10:40:09
3   12  2022-08-07  14:40:09    16:40:09
4   13  2022-08-07  09:22:45    17:57:06
```

Trying a different approach:

```
df=df[['ID','Date','Time']]

def check(x):
    x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
    if len(x)%2!=0:
        x=x.drop(len(x)-2)
    return x

df
df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg(check)

g = df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg(check).explode('Time').reset_index(drop=True)

g['in'] = np.where(g.index%2==0, g.loc[g.index,'Time'], np.nan)
g['out'] = np.where(g.index%2!=0, g.loc[g.index,'Time'], np.nan)

out = g.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg(list)
out['in'] = out['in'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if str(i) != "nan"])
out['out'] = out['out'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if str(i) != "nan"])
out[['ID','Date','in','out']].explode(['in','out']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    ID  Date        in          out
0   10  2022-08-07  07:40:09    12:40:09
1   10  2022-08-08  07:40:09    17:40:09
2   12  2022-08-07  08:03:09    10:40:09
2   12  2022-08-07  14:40:09    16:40:09
3   13  2022-08-07  09:22:45    17:57:06
```

Comment: Hi Yaloa_21 thanks for your answer , but i got this error                                             `indexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: Try: `if len(suffix)%2!=0 and len(suffix)>1`.

Comment: i received another error `ValueError: Length of values (2623) does not match length of index (2667)`

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. There was a typo in the code: `suffix = sorted(list(range(1,len(d)))*2)[:len(p)]` should be `suffix = sorted(list(range(1,len(p)))*2)[:len(p)]`. - there is a 'd' instead of a 'p' (I should have used more explicative variables names!).

Comment: still the same error , the output you showed is the exactly what i want

Comment: I'm not sure why. I have tried the code on the sample data you provided and also used `df.sample(100, replacement=True)` to test it on a larger dataset, and it works. So maybe there is something in the original data that differs from the sample data enough to cause the error - but mainly the error is caused from `new_col` not having the same length as the df. Maybe it is given by some NaN values? Have you tried `df=df.dropna()` before executing the rest of the code?

Comment: yes i did ,maybe because my data is missing something because like i told you sometimes its missing a checkout , but your algorithm is correct idk what the problem is

Comment: Have you tried removing this line: `suffix[-2]=np.nan`?

Comment: Yes its always the same problem

Comment: I have tried one other attempt, let me know if this works!

Comment: and another one !`~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5280         if mask.any():
   5281             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5282                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   5283             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5284         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: '[-1] not found in axis'`